# Using Run Script flow to call webhook when a file gets created

Tags: webhooks, nextcloud

## Task at hand

I want to execute a simple curl command to trigger a webhook when a new file arrives.

## Setup

I am using a NextCloud Linux container and installed `Workflow external scripts`.

## Configuration

- When `File created` and `File name` `matches` `/.*/`
- Then Pass files to external scripts for processing outside of Next Cloud `/usr/bin/curl http://mywebhook -d "%n"`

## Troubleshooting Steps

- Made sure that curl is installed at that path
- There is no proxy that may block the connection
- curl invoked on the shell inside the container works
- Access log of external webserver shows that webhook is not being triggered
- Cannot find more debug output output of the NextCloud flow
- Used the script Flow Notifications with same parameters and get notified of new files

## Questions

- What can I do to further troubleshoot this issue?
- Is there anyone that successfully uses the external script flow?
- Is it possible to alternatively tap into some NextCloud event notification from external (did not found an API for that)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it works as designed. It only triggers, when files get created via NextCloud GUI. https://help.nextcloud.com/t/using-workflow-external-script-to-generate-searchable-pdf/94785